# Cloning a predicate

Tags: java, predicate

I wanted to clone a Predicate object, my first attempt was:

```
Predicate<String> p1 = str -> str.isEmpty();
Predicate<String> p2 = str -> p1.test(str);
```

But in that case, if p1 change, p2 change too. Is there a way to clone a Predicate so that p2 do not change?

Comment: What's being cloned here? Your predicates are stateless, so you shouldn't have a problem.

Comment: Why can't you reuse the old one?

Comment: Introduce another variable. If tou let p1 be final and introduce p3=p1, you can use p1 as the unchangeable and p3 as the mutable ref.

Comment: Besides, all variables captured by closures have to be final or effectively final.

Comment: By 'clone', I don't mean the java clone method, It mean copy, having a new Predicate that behave the same

Comment: No functional type should ever change, really.  This should be completely unnecessary all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you are facing is not that the predicate is going to change, but that one of the external variables referenced by the predicate implicitly is going to change. Therefore, making a copy of the predicate would not help, because it is already immutable.

Making a temporary variable to capture `p1`'s value should fix this problem:

```
Predicate<String> p1 = str -> str.isEmpty();
final Predicate<String> pTemp = p1;
Predicate<String> p2 = str -> pTemp.test(str);
```

The reason the fix works is that when you re-assign `p1`, the old predicate object does not get modified; it gets replaced with a completely new predicate instance. The old predicate object still exists, but, in the absence of live references, it becomes eligible for garbage collection.

When you add `pTemp`, the old predicate becomes referenced from two variables - namely, `p1` and `pTemp`. At this point, re-assigning `p1` has no effect on `pTemp`, so the behavior of `p2` would remain unchanged as well.

I imagine this would be more useful in a loop, when you build a predicate incrementally.

Comment: Thank you, that works, although I understand why, can you explain what's happening behind the scene please?

Comment: Besides the uselessness of the cloning per se, you can simply use `Predicate<String> p2 = p1::test;` to bind `p1` to the new `Predicate` permanently. Then, subsequent changes to `p1` have no effect to `p2`. To illustrate, why the cloning is useless, you can achieve the same by simply using `Predicate<String> p2 = p1;`, it does not clone, but have the same effect, the predicates referred by `p1` and `p2` have the same behavior and subsequent changes to `p1` have no effect on `p2`…